# importing winston causes 'process is not defined'

Tags: javascript, svelte, winston, sveltekit

I am creating an app with sveltekit and am currently adding logging.

Simple enough in the backend with winston as it works pretty much out of the box.

But I am running into some issues with importing it on the frontend.

my code is pretty simple

```html
<script>
    import winston from 'winston';
    import { Card } from '../components/issue/';

    export let project;
</script>
```

but that simple snippet seems to throw this error

```
500
process is not defined

ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at node_modules/colors/lib/system/supports-colors.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/winston.js?v=b8878498:281:15)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-JAKTRAE2.js?v=b8878498:6:44)
    at node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/winston.js?v=b8878498:714:28)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-JAKTRAE2.js?v=b8878498:6:44)
    at node_modules/colors/safe.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/winston.js?v=b8878498:850:18)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-JAKTRAE2.js?v=b8878498:6:44)
    at node_modules/logform/dist/colorize.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/winston.js?v=b8878498:881:18)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-JAKTRAE2.js?v=b8878498:6:44)
    at node_modules/logform/dist/levels.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/winston.js?v=b8878498:953:20)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-JAKTRAE2.js?v=b8878498:6:44)
```

I honestly have no real idea of what could be wrong other that it possibly being an issue with server/client side rendering.

so I guess the question is: can you import winston in a sveltekit project, and if so how?
and is there any workarounds to this specific issue?

Comment: winston appears to be made for nodejs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [can't use Winston in the browser](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/287) right now, although support for it is currently on roadmap.